# How can I create a domain global deployable module? (Jboss, Wildfly)

Tags: jboss, wildfly8

Has anyone created or used a deployable module pushed out to slaves (from the Domain Host-Controller) without a separate script or step to update the {JBOSS_HOME}/modules/ directory? I would like to be able to push out updates to a module centrally, or, if that is not possible, is there a way to detect if a slave has a different version of the module installed (than the Master)?

(I am running Wildfly 8.2, but JBOSS solution would likely apply also)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `patch` feature, this allow apply updates in the servers installations from domain controller. Also you can view patch history and verify patch.

Eg (cli command).

```
patch --host=server.local apply /<path_to_patch>/patch.zip
```

You can see a full example in: [Patch User Defined WildFly Modules in Domain Mode](http://aparnachaudhary.github.io/blog/2014/11/wildfly-patch-custom-module.html)

See also: [Layered Distributions and Module Path Organization](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/LayeredDistributionsAndModulePathOrganization)